# What is the meaning of "Rapidly improving rap sheet."?

Tags: meaning

It's the drama dialogue and background is the police office.

The detective said like this about the suspect.

> Name. Klaus Goedecke. Size twelve wide. **Rapidly improving** rap sheet. Recently made a sizable cash deposit

In this sentence, what is the meaning of "Rapidly improving"? I know rap sheet means criminal report.

Comment: The word "improving" is meant ironically.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks, but I still don't get it - Rapidly Ironically rap sheet. Does it means he is ex-convict?

Comment: As if the rap sheet were his CV.    It is "improving" in the sense that new crimes are being added to it, as new jobs are added to a resume during the course of one's career.  It is sarcasm.  (I'm not suggesting that you substitute the word "ironically" for the word "improving".)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at [No. 2 definition of *intransitive verb*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/improve):

> to make useful additions or amendments

A crime can't be a useful addition unless it is used in a *sarcastic* or *ironic* sense as TRomano commented.

"Improving" in the sentence could be replaced by "growing" or "increasing", but it won't have such a sarcastic or ironic sense.

Answer (score 1):

The mention of "Rapidly improving" in a positive reference could mean:

Pardoned/ Exonerated/ Expungment of a crime from the rap sheet.

Comment: It's not what we would typically expect, but it could be used that way in the correct context, and I'm glad you pointed it out. I think we would be more likely to say "rapidly **shrinking** rap sheet" instead of improving in that situation, although there are a lot of different ways it could be phrased, especially in a drama.